# Python import throws an OS: module not found error for vlc

Tags: python, vlc

So, i installed some stuff for python, and going through all my imports and trying to pip install them gives me a 'Requirement already satisfied'. When I run a script though, everytime i debug to

```
import vlc
```

I get a

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

directly instead of passing through to the next import. if i comment out this import, it works up to the point where I use it. I am using VSCode, my python version is set to 3.7.1, so that is not the problem. I rarely work with python, so I do not know what else I can do at this point.

Comment: Are you installing the module with `pip` or `pip3`? You might have the module installed to a different version then you are actually running.

Comment: @MattClark i did both, and both gave me a 'satisfied'. that was my first idea also and i realised i did it with pip, so i did pip3 afterwards. hope that doesn't screw it up, because pip3 after pip said 'satisfied'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While obvious to some, I did not know that VLC was Traffic Cone (tm) video player, and probably should have read the vlc docs.

**You need to have the actual VLC installed on you PC for the vlc import to work with python**